# pandas_datareader._utils.RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/CBOE

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

I'm trying to extract the S&P500 list from wikipedia; however, when I run the code, it only extracts 90 companies, and it gives this giant error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python projects/Pandas_1/S&P500 Tickers.py", line 46, in <module>
    get_data_from_yahoo()
  File "D:/Python projects/Pandas_1/S&P500 Tickers.py", line 37, in get_data_from_yahoo
    df = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
  File "C:\Users\UserX\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py", line 310, in DataReader
    session=session).read()
  File "C:\Users\UserX\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 210, in read
    params=self._get_params(self.symbols))
  File "C:\Users\UserX\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\yahoo\daily.py", line 129, in _read_one_data
    resp = self._get_response(url, params=params)
  File "C:\Users\UserX\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 155, in _get_response
    raise RemoteDataError(msg)
pandas_datareader._utils.RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/CBOE: CBOE/history?period1=1262311200&period2=1547776799&interval=1d&frequency=1d&filter=history
```

And the response code, which is too large to fit into this post.
I am a newbie, so I don't know what to try. My code is:

```
import bs4 as bs
import datetime as dt
import os
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pickle
import requests


def save_sp500_tickers():
    resp = requests.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable'})
    tickers = []
    for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
        ticker = row.findAll('td')[0].text
        tickers.append(ticker)
    with open("sp500tickers.pickle", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(tickers, f)
    return tickers


def get_data_from_yahoo(reload_sp500=False):
    if reload_sp500:
        tickers = save_sp500_tickers()
    else:
        with open("sp500tickers.pickle", "rb") as f:
            tickers = pickle.load(f)
    if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs'):
        os.makedirs('stock_dfs')

    start = dt.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
    end = dt.datetime.now()
    for ticker in tickers:
        if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker)):
            df = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
            df.reset_index(inplace=True)
            df.set_index("Date", inplace=True)
            df = df.drop("Symbol", axis=1)
            df.to_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
        else:
            print('Already have {}'.format(ticker))


get_data_from_yahoo()
```

Comment: Your code works for me, it can scrape `CBOE` successfully. (I removed `df = df.drop("Symbol", axis=1)` and call `get_data_from_yahoo(True)`)

Comment: The response code is likely to be important